# Creating new user beside root in docker-compose having connections issues

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode, docker-stack

I  am running a docker stack using the docker-compose . The docker-compose.yml looks something like below. The problem is if I add the default user root then it works fine but changing the user to another user say **tara** throws an error.

**I repeat:**
*Works well for user: root*

***Note I am running it on 3 nodes  with single replica. So the service may be running in any of the nodes.***

```
"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host '10.0.10.6' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = ramesh@gm ▶"
```

**Here is the docker-compose.yml**

version: '3.3'

networks:
  smstake: 
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.0.10.0/24

services:

```
db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    networks:
      - smstake
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: smstake
      MYSQL_USER: tara
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1

app:

    image: smstake:latest
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    networks:
      - smstake
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager

phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    networks:
      - smstake
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      MYSQL_USER: tara
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - '8082:80'
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
```

volumes:
    db_data:

**All 3 services are running just a issues with connections.**

> People are suggesting to run grant commands  but where and how can I
>   make those commands run ?

Comment: You should specify that this is a mysql question in the title, tags, and first paragraph. Also, use code formatting on the compose file so the first few lines do not show as normal text.

Answer (score 1):

Show running process

```
docker ps
```

Connect to mysql running container

```
docker exec -it MYSQL-CONTAINER-NAME /bin/bash
```

Once inside the container, connect to database and create user and whatever.

Comment: I don't want to put any manual tasks .How can it be automated.

Comment: go to the repo of your docker image https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/tree/master/5.7 and figure it out looking at the https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh. After this you can edit your Dockerfile to create your user

Comment: looks like it already has this options  `file_env 'MYSQL_USER'
  file_env 'MYSQL_PASSWORD'
  if [ "$MYSQL_USER" -a "$MYSQL_PASSWORD" ]; then
   echo "CREATE USER '$MYSQL_USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$MYSQL_PASSWORD' ;" | "${mysql[@]}"

   if [ "$MYSQL_DATABASE" ]; then
    echo "GRANT ALL ON \`$MYSQL_DATABASE\`.* TO '$MYSQL_USER'@'%' ;" | "${mysql[@]}"
   fi

   echo 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES ;' | "${mysql[@]}"
fi`

Comment: Aha .. so make -this enviroments variables avaible from your docker-compose.yml

Comment: Try to do docker exec -it MYSQL-CONTAINER-NAME /bin/bash and echo $MYSQL_USER to see if you have it inside the docker container

Comment: yes it do exist both the username and password . but when trying to login using new user or even with the *root* user throws `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` . Tried inside the docker container

Comment: Try to create your .Dockerfile that pulls from the image you are using and in your docker-compose.yml delete de image entry and add a "build" entry pointing to the path of your .Dockerfile

Comment: But I should connect to the database and create the user manually... as your DB is mapped with a volume you only have to do it once.